# Destroy Backbone model using async=false

Tags: backbone.js

I try to pass `{async: false}` to the `destroy` function of my model but it doesn't work:

```
m.destroy({
    async: false,
    success: function(){
        console.log('destroyed');
    }
});

console.log('already destroyed');
```

I see the second log before the first one. Am I missing something or async doesn't work for destroy?

Comment: The [`destroy` docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-destroy) tell you what options are available.

Comment: ok, so how is it possible to do it synchronously?

Comment: I'd guess that you'd have to override the `ajax` or `sync` methods. But really, it is best to pretend that the `async:false` option doesn't exist, it is a nasty and rude thing to do to your users.

Answer (score 0):

Please look for my project which was created for testing Backbone-Debugger (Chrome plugin)

- https://github.com/piecioshka/test-backbone-debugger

Please let me know, if it's helpful!

Comment: Thanks but you just call `destroy` which does it async. Am I right?

Comment: My own `destroy` - https://github.com/piecioshka/test-backbone-debugger/blob/master/scripts/app.js#L6